# Blender 3.1.2 UV-Seam will cause visual seam in baked normal map (Highpoly -> LowPoly)

Tags: uv, edges, baking, normal-map, artifacts

A lot of threads exist because of this problems, but no answer solved the problem so far for me. My baked normal maps (Cycles) will always have visible sharp edges with artifacts wherever i "mark seam" for UV-Unwraping. I testet this with a 1:1 clone of my Cube, only the UV-Seams have been rearranged. The normalmap-edges followed exactly to the new position of the UV-Seams.

[Blend-File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KYjsp2rzwtpuuWmL1IPQi9xBmbbSxs_J/view?usp=sharing)

1. I use 32-Bit-Float for image format 4096x4096
2. I checked colorspace "non-color" in the Texture Image node
3. tried to smooth the Cube-edges with subsurf in the LP-Cube - no effect
4. Tried to use an additional clone as resized cage - no effect

Here is a Video, that demonstrates the problem.

[**click for Video-Demonstration**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnL4KyzjBos)

[image: Node-Setup]

I copied the lowpoly Cube and give him unique material and image texture, but the overall settings & bake options did not change. I changed the UV-Seam and you see at the bottom cube (OK-Arrow), that there are no lines and it looks fine. The upper cube shows a sharp cut there (there is a uv-seam). So simply dragging the marked seams to another edge, will also move the unpleasant edge-effect in the normal map. Any solution for that?

[image: Comparison of cloned Cube]

Answer (score 0):

maby try adding a cage, if you what a easy way to do this try this addon
https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender I use this for most of my baking and it works well.

Comment: Oh - of course i also tried the cage way :) does not make any difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, are you using blender internal baking system, if so maby try some baking addons

Comment: im actually more interessted to find out what im missing out - or if it is a flaw since Cycles is the only way to bake textures. I read about such problems in many threads. Some of them stay without any usefull answer. What is your opinion about it? Is this a result that is alright or is it faulty? Might report it as bug.

Comment: As I said I mostly use addon, but they still use the internal baking system. This kind of looks like their is no padding on the baked map. Can you post a image of the normal map? Or tell me if their is padding in the baked map?

Comment: If you are refering to the Margin-settings of the normal bake -> yes, there is. I wonder if the padding-function might not work as intended. The borders of the UV-seam always get "dirty" in some way. The files are all in the blend File included.

Comment: I got the file and tried baking it myself, the error presisted no mater what I did, I used bolth of my addons to no avail. My opinion is this is a bug do to the teribble baking system in blender. I can;t figer out a workaround other than baking in another program, hop this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In *UV Editor > UV > Seams from Island*, and also select the mesh then go to *Mesh > Shade Smooth*.

Then rebake in substance.